# Unable to invoke the apis in two website instances with same assembly name in iis7

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I'm having a site hosted in IIS as 'SiteA' and I need to show the same site with some theme change as 'SiteB'.

The sites are published to the inetpub under the following folder structure:

```
Fold1/SiteA

Fold1/SiteB
```

With these, I'm able to see the webpages. The apis I'm calling within the SiteB is returning 404 error.

What could be the reason? Isn't it possible to take two separate sites out of same project?

Kindly help.

Comment: Could you post the code that is responsible for the API calls ? Also, post the differences between SiteA and SiteB if you can.

Comment: The webapplication is having a set of apis and as per my understanding it should be calling the corresponding virtual path on deployment. i.e, my webapp has few apis and i loaded SiteA first and those api calls are working fine for SiteA. Then i created another virtual folder with a newly published code from the same webapp and there my api calls are refering to the right path but it says 404. How can that be a cross domain call?

Comment: Can you post two examples of the API calls ? One that succeds, and one  that fails.

Comment: It cant be wrong, because, in my ajax call im using the virtual paths. For siteA : "Fold1/SiteA/api/Register/Get" and for siteB: "Fold2/SiteB/api/Register/Get" The apis are part of the same website. So separate calls should work i guess.

Comment: Yes they should, but without any additionnal info I can't help you much ... Are you 100% sure the deployed websites are identical (use WinMerge for instance to compare the two folders), particularly the web.config files ?

Comment: Can you tell me what all i need to give? I dont know much about deployment and IIS

Comment: The websites are identical. Because, i copied and pasted the dll of SiteA to create SiteB and then it wasnt working, then i tried to publish the dll from its original webapp and tried. Still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In IIS Add Virtual Directory Fold1. Make SiteA and SiteB 'convert to Application'.

Then you can access like: localhost/Fold1/SiteA   and localhost/Fold1/SiteB

And errors you mentioned can be 'cos of invalid url path to your api.

Comment: The path is correct, I want to know whether some conflicts happen on deploying same set of dll in two different path within the same application pool

Comment: Well, it is hard to say what might be wrong, while I cannot see how you call api. But if there are conflicts in dll, then you probably will get 505.

Comment: @deepak No, there are no conflicts about identical assemblies within the same pool. Websites are isolated within an application pool. The application pool is just a process that handles requests and routes them to the appropriate application. But Dmitry is right, as long as you don't give more information, we can't help you much.